# Replace a value in a column matching a particular pattern in R

Tags: regex, r

I am new to R and i am not able to find how to do this.

Consider a table named Trial like this

```
  Col1  Col2            Col3 
   1    hey    June 24, 2013 5:15:06 PM GMT+05:30
   2    hello  april 20, 2013 5:15:06 PM GMT+05:30
   3    hey    July 23, 2012 5:15:06 PM GMT+05:30
```

How do i replace values of Col3 in Trial to

```
  Col1  Col2       Col3 
   1    hey      June 2013 
   2    hello    april 2013 
   3    hey      July 2012
```

ie.i need to extract only month and year and make a new column or replace in the same. 
Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for example:

```
 dat$Col3 <- gsub('(^\\w+).*, ([0-9]{4}).*','\\1 \\2',dat$Col3)
```